# Сортировка массива JavaScript

Tags: массивы, javascript, сортировка

Здравствуйте.
Имеется массив:

```
[
  {
    "id":15364842,
    "date":1364244632,
    "src":"GeZA4v2l-Vo.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id":3549623,
    "date":1364245503,
    "src":"pIMhRV5nf_Y.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id":15364165,
    "date":1364243193,
    "src":"LMnKzmNZ390.jpg"
  }
]
```

В каждом элементе хранится картинка с идентификатором и timestamp. Возможно ли отсортировать все эти записи по полю Date по убыванию? Если решение кажется вам сомнительным - предложите пожалуйста, как сделать лучше.

Заранее огромное спасибо.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
array = array.sort(function (b, a) {
    //если результат <0 то b должен быть впереди a
    return (a.date - b.date)
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/4AGf7/

Comment: Премного благодарен.